# How does the Nelson-Oppen combination handle shared variables that are equal but interpreted as unequal constants in different theories?

Tags: logic, smt, theorem-proving, first-order-logic

I've read Chapter 10 from (https://www.decision-procedures.org/) and come up with a question of Nelson-Oppen combination under a specific situation (I'll try to state the question w.r.t. the definitions from the book):

Consider the combination of two theories, *T_1* and *T_2*, where *V* is the set of *shared variables*, and a *constant symbol* is a (nonlogical) function symbol with arity 0.

After the *purification* step, *F_1* is the conjunction of *T_1-literals* and *F_2* is the conjunction of *T_2-literals*.

Then think of a situation that *F_1* implies *v_1=v_2=x*,
and *F_2* implies *v_1=v_2=y*, but *x ≠ y*.

(*v_1, v_2* belong to *V*, *x* is a constant symbol of *T_1*, and *y* is a constant symbol of *T_2*.

Based on my understanding, Nelson-Oppen combination only propagates equalities between shared variables(*v_1, v_2*) and does not detect the situation which causes inconsistent.

So, my question is:
Does Nelson-Oppen combination prevent or deal with this situation?

Also, I couldn't think of a case using the combination of theories introduced in the book (such as the theory of linear arithmetic, equality and uninterpreted functions, arrays). I'm wondering if this situation actually happens or there is just something that I misunderstand.